# Why does the type change to Real in z3 python?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I was checking the sort for some operations in z3py and ran into the following:

```
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
print((1 + (2 + (x*(y**2)))).sort())
```

which outputs

```
Real
```

Why does the type of the expression result in a Real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `**` (exponentiation) operator always returns a `Real` in z3, even if the arguments are integers. Note that if the second argument is negative, then the result will not be an integer.

Compare:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> x, y, z = Ints('x y z')
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(And(x == 2, y == -1, z == x ** y))
>>> print(s.check())
unsat
```

to:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> x, y = Ints('x y')
>>> z = Real('z')
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(And(x == 2, y == -1, z == x ** y))
>>> print(s.check())
sat
>>> print(s.model())
[z = 1/2, y = -1, x = 2]
```

If you want an integer-only producing version of exponentiation, you can code it yourself by enforcing all results to be equal to some existential `Int`.

Note that the power operator is usually difficult to deal with in SMT solvers due to non-linearity, and undecidable in general due to the undecidability of Diophantine equations. So unless the constraints are easy enough you'll most likely get `unknown` as an answer at best, or the solver will loop forever.